# if I use bind_all, can I make exceptions for some widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

It occurred to me to make use of `event.widget.winfo_parent()`, but it returns a `str` with the full path of the `widget` and I can't grab wrapper to put it inside an `if` to prevent the statement block from executing. Hence my question if there is a more correct method to do this or some way to grab the container, in this case from  of `self.btn` and use it in a statement. Thanks

**The challenge is making exceptions between buttons, in the example I only put two, but what do I do if I want the exception to be for a few buttons and not all?**

```py
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame)
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='yellow')
        self.frame .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
         
        self.cnt = Frame(self.frame, bg='green2')
        self.cnt .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.btn = Button(self.cnt, text='Button 1 ')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn2 = Button(self.cnt, text='Button 2')
        self.btn2.pack()
        

        self.bind_all('<Motion-1>', self.hellow)

    def hellow(self, event):
        print('I always run how I want')

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
app .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` to check weather the widget is a `Button` or whatever.

```
def hellow(self, event):
    if not isinstance(event.widget,Button):
        print('I always run how I want, except when hovered over buttons')
```

This will run the `print` every time you hover over any widget other than `Button`. But keep in mind, this will run `hellow` for every widget, but it wont execute the code put inside the `if` block for the avoided widget.

**After the question is updated:**
You can create a list with buttons to avoid and then just check if the widget belongs in the list.

```
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='yellow')
        self.frame .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.cnt = Frame(self.frame, bg='green2')
        self.cnt .pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.btn = Button(self.cnt, text='First')
        self.btn.pack()

        self.btn1 = Button(self.cnt, text='Second')
        self.btn1.pack()

        self.btn2 = Button(self.cnt, text='Third')
        self.btn2.pack()

        self.bind_all('<Motion>', self.hellow)

        self.to_avoid = [self.btn1,self.btn2] # Buttons to avoid list

    def hellow(self, event):
        if event.widget not in self.to_avoid:
            print('I always run how I want, except for some widgets')
```

Comment: **Thanks for your answer** but, the challenge is making **exceptions** between ```buttons```, in the example I only put one was my mistake, but what do I do if I want the **exception** to be for a few ```buttons``` and not all?

Comment: @JackieCk Should have mentioned it earlier, anyway updated the answer

Comment: You are right and your answer was adequate for the question I asked, I will ask the question again with the actual scope that I am working with. Thank you very much for your timely reply.

Comment: Excuse my insistence but it is not logical that if I put in the example ```bind_all``` I am talking about a very large environment in which the ```buttons``` or ```widgets``` have different parents. And hence the logical use of ```bind_all```.

Comment: @JackieCk Parent doesn't matter here....

Comment: @JackieCk Sorry, I do not understand your question. How can you not have a WM..?

Comment: My environment works with many windows, it does not have the window manager, so use ```bind_all``` declaration for all widgets to move the windows. What I am trying to do is make exceptions for some widgets, I thought of ```event.widget.winfo_parent()```. and using the ```str``` that returns as a condition, it works but it's very caveman and I don't think it's the right thing to do. Hence my question to find the parent of the widget arises.

Comment: @JackieCk This is same as what you said earlier, still doesnt make sense. How can a window not have a window manager? Better to ask a new question with sufficient details

Comment: with:  overrideredirect(True).

Comment: @JackieCk Ask a new question please, let me see what I can infer

Comment: I already asked the question again ... I added the fraction of the code in question where I have the problem to find the parent of the widgets