# if I use bind_all globally, can I make exceptions for some widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I will detail the most relevant data in my code, what I intend is to find an efficient way to do checks that exclude a widget in this case it will be `self._btn_1`and `self._btn_2`

1. What this application does is create two windows without window manager, you can move the windows by dragging the mouse by clicking anywhere.
2. The structure of the presented code is exaggerated for demonstration purposes of the true structure of my script.

This function is linked to the entire application and is responsible for moving the windows. And this is where the verification should go, as you can see in the final part, that's how it occurred to me to do the validation so that when dragging the mouse the window does not move. Thanks.

```py
def on_move2(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self._x
        deltay = event.y - self._y
        win = event.widget.winfo_toplevel()

        new_position = "+{}+{}".format(win.winfo_x() + deltax, win.winfo_y() + deltay)
        win.geometry(new_position) 

        #print('print:', event.widget.winfo_parent())
        if event.widget.winfo_parent() == '.!a1.!toplevel.!frame.!frame.!label':
            print('You found me but you have 0')
```

**From here the complete script begins.**

```py
from tkinter import *

class Move():
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0
    def start_move2(self, event):        
        self._x = event.x
        self._y = event.y
    def stop_move2(self, event):
        self._x = None
        self._y = None
    def on_move2(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self._x
        deltay = event.y - self._y
        win = event.widget.winfo_toplevel()

        new_position = "+{}+{}".format(win.winfo_x() + deltax, win.winfo_y() + deltay)
        win.geometry(new_position) 

        #print('print:', event.widget.winfo_parent())
        if event.widget.winfo_parent() == '.!a1.!toplevel.!frame.!frame.!label':
            print('You found me but you have 0')
```

```py
class A1 (Frame, Move):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.btn = Button(self, text='opens', command=self.open)
        self.btn .pack()

        self.bind_all("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_move2)
        self.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move2)
        self.bind_all("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_move2)

    def open(self):
        self.w1 = Toplevel(self)
        self.w1 .overrideredirect(1)
        self.w1 .wm_attributes ('-topmost', True)        
        self.w2 = Toplevel(self)
        self.w2 .overrideredirect(1)
        self.w2. wm_attributes ('-topmost', True) 

        self.w1 .geometry('300x150')
        self.w2 .geometry('300x150')

        self.frame_1 = Frame(self.w1, bg='green')
        self.label_1 = Label(self.frame_1, text='___windows 1___', bg='green2', width=50)
        self.btn_1 = Button(self.label_1, text='AAAAAAA')

        self._frame_1 = Frame(self.frame_1, bg='green')
        self._label_1 = Label(self._frame_1, text='windows 1', bg='green2', width=50)
        self._btn_1 = Button(self._label_1, text='button 2 - A')   #
        self._bbn_11 = Button(self._label_1, text='button 3 - A')

        self.frame_2 = Frame(self.w2, bg='green')
        self.label_2 = Label(self.frame_2, text='___windows 2___', bg='green2', width=50)
        self.btn_2 = Button(self.label_2, text='BBBBBBB')

        self._frame_2 = Frame(self.frame_2, bg='green')
        self._label_2 = Label(self._frame_2, text='windows 1', bg='green2', width=50)
        self._btn_2 = Button(self._label_2, text='button 2 - B')
        self._bbn_22 = Button(self._label_2, text='button 3 - B')

        self.frame_1 .pack()
        self.label_1 .pack()
        self.btn_1 .pack()
        self._frame_1 .pack()
        self._label_1 .pack()
        self._btn_1 .pack()
        self._bbn_11 .pack()
        
        self.frame_2 .pack()
        self.label_2 .pack()
        self.btn_2 .pack()
        self._frame_2 .pack()
        self._label_2 .pack()
        self._btn_2 .pack()
        self._bbn_22 .pack()

root = Tk()
app = A1(root, bg='black')
app .pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
root .mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `bind_all`, why are you not binding to the toplevel itself?

Comment: So...? You can still do this with any number of toplevels?

Comment: It would be better if you could craft an example that has more than 1 toplevel, having a `overrideredict` on it, alone with the bindings you made on them

Comment: It seems like you've already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460228/if-i-use-bind-all-can-i-make-exceptions-for-some-widgets). How is this question different?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. You're free to do whatever checks you want in your bound functions. It's not clear what criteria you want to use in the bindings.

Comment: @BryanOakley The most important criteria is to use ```event.widget``` in the **verification** and to use what it returns in a unit **verification**, which distinguishes the widget from any other widget **in the entire application**. As the name of the widget itself. If I had to read the syntax it would be this:
```If the widget named A-5 equals A-5:```

Comment: @JackieCk: What is stopping you from doing that? Why do you need to compare against a name rather than against an actual widget? Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Should I ask another question or edit this one?

Comment: Edit this one. We don't need three questions for a single problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley All widgets should allow you to move the window except [```self._btn_1``` and ```self._btn_2```]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude a specific widget, arguably the simplest solution is to add that widget to a list, and then compare `event.widget` to that list.

Start by extending the `Move` class to have a list of unmovable widgets, a method for adding widgets to the list, and a method to determine if a widget is movable.

```
class Move():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self._unmovable = []
        
    def make_unmovable(self, *widgets):
        self._unmovable.extend(widgets)
        
    def _is_movable(self, widget):
        return widget not in self._unmovable
    ...
```

Then, you can add widgets to the unmovable list when you create them, and check to see if they are in the list when handling the events.

```
def on_move2(self, event):
    if not self._is_movable(event.widget):
        return
    ...
```

You need to make sure `Move.__init__` is called in A1:

```
class A1 (Frame, Move):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        Move.__init__(self)
        ...
```

and finally, add widgets you don't want to be movable to the list:

```
class A1 (Frame, Move):
    ...
    def open(self):
        ...
        self._btn_1 = Button(self._label_1, text='button 2 - A')   #
        self._btn_2 = Button(self._label_2, text='button 2 - B')
        ...
        self.make_unmovable(self._btn_1, self._btn_2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the result was satisfactory.